# Find $\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx$ when $f_{(x)}=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$ using $f_{(\pi)}=\beta$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

There's a hint included in this question to use integration by parts.

Find $\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx$ when $f_{(x)}=\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$ using $f_{(\pi)}=\beta$

Here are my attempts:

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx=\displaystyle\int_0^\pi 1(\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t})dx$$
$$u' = 1, v=\displaystyle\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}=f_{(x)}$$
$$u = x, v' =f'_{(x)}$$

($v'=f_{(x)}$ because  $(F_{(x)}-F_{(0)})'=f_{(x)}-f_{(0)}=f_{(x)}$)

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx=uv-\displaystyle\int_0^\pi uv'dx=\pi f_{(\pi)}-\displaystyle\int_0^\pi xf'_{(x)}dx$$

Using integration by parts

$$\pi f_{(\pi)}-(\pi f_{(\pi)}-\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx)$$
Which leads me to a trivial $$\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx=\displaystyle\int_0^\pi f_{(x)}dx$$

Any hints?

Comment: There is no need to put arguments as subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Integration by parts tells you that
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\,dx=
\Bigl[xf(x)\Bigr]_0^{\pi}
-\int_0^\pi xf'(x)\,dx
$$
Now compute $f'(x)$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: The first "part" is the constant function with the value $1$ and the second "part" is $f(x)$.

Comment: @Wauzl Yes, $u'=1$ and $v=f(x)$, so you get $uv-\int uv'\,dx$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to integration by parts is to change the order of integration.
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi}f(x)dx&=\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}t\,dt\,dx=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\sin t}t\int_t^{\pi}dx\,dt\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}\left(\pi\frac{\sin t}t-\sin t\right)dt=\pi f(\pi)+\left.\cos t\right|_0^{\pi}\\
&=\pi\beta-2\end{align}$$